# Foreign key with large table vs small table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

Does foreign key relation with larger table has any performance impact ?

```
CREATE TABLE CHARTOFACCOUNT --Contains all accounts
(
    AccountNo VARCHAR(23) PRIMARY KEY,
    --,
)

CREATE TABLE DEPOSITACCOUNT --Contains all deposit accounts(row less than CHARTOFACCOUNT)
(
    AccountNo VARCHAR(23) PRIMARY KEY,
    --,
)

CREATE TABLE DEPOSITACCOUNTSTATUS --Contains all Deposit account status 1 to 1 relation
(
    AccountNo VARCHAR(23) PRIMARY KEY,
    --,    
)
```

`DEPOSITACCOUNT` has foreign key relation with `CHARTOFACCOUNT`. Now when its come for `DEPOSITACCOUNTSTATUS`, I could make foreign key relation with `DEPOSITACCOUNT` or `CHARTOFACCOUNT` and both will be valid. But as `CHARTOFACCOUNT` contains more rows than `DEPOSITACCOUNT` is there any performance issue exists?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Performance questions are almost always product specific.)

Comment: currently for MS SQL Server 2012 and later versions but I would prefer to know if others has any issues different

Comment: Primary keys on integers work better than those on varchars.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed agreed. But that wasn't my concern.

Comment: I dont think that setting the correct foreign keys will ever cost any performance. Suppose you dont set them, how do you make sure your referential integretie stays intact ? You will have to run queries yourself to do that and that will always be slower than what a foreign key does

Comment: You are correct. To check data integrity manually is of course more costly. But there is a debate exists that foreign keys cost any performance or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a case of premature optimisation.

Choose your foreign keys based on the system you are trying to model, not just because you *think* there might be a performance issue.

You say:

> I could make foreign key relation with DEPOSITACCOUNT or
>   CHARTOFACCOUNT and both will be valid

This makes me think you could have a problem with your design. What does the `CHARTOFACCOUNT` table store that is different to the `DEPOSITACCOUNT` table?

Why are deposit accounts treated differently to other account types? Why not store them in an `Account` table with the type being an attribute?

And why is the deposit account status being stored separately from the account itself? If there is a one-to-one relationship between the tables you could move that information in to the `Account` table.

Comment: look `CHARTOFACCOUNT` contains all accounts and the common information of them where as `DEPOSITACCOUNT` contains only deposit accounts and deposit relevant information. Design issue is not there. Design issue is I could merge the `DEPOSITACCOUNTSTATUS` table with `DEPOSITACCOUNT` as they contain same number of rows 1 to 1. But in this situation which table would be better to join with `DEPOSITACCOUNTSTATUS` ???

Comment: If you don't want to combine the account status in to the deposit table then, logically, it should have a foreign key to the `DEPOITACCOUNT` table. It is a deposit account status, after all.

Comment: Yeah currently it was also like that. But as `CHARTOFACCOUNT` contains all deposit accounts then if I do relation with it instead of `DEPOSITACCOUNT` data integrity will not be violated. But is there any catch here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "data integrity will not be violated" - why would setting the foreign key to the `DEPOSITACCOUNT` table cause an integrity violation?

Comment: No I just said that, using `DEPOSITACCOUNT` is fine. Of course more secure is to make relation with `DEPOSITACCOUNT` . But if I use `CHARTOFACCOUNT` for relation then it will also work with some integrity violation issues like someone could insert a loan account information in `DEPOSITACCOUNTSTATUS` table. But my concern is different. Relation with larger table does make any performance drawbacks? During insert or update child table information if relation exists with larger table then system will have to seek among larger amount of data, this kind of issues I am talking about.

Comment: I have to refer you back to the first line of my answer: This sounds like a case of premature optimisation.

Unless you have your own proof of a performance issue, put the foreign key _where it makes the most sense_. I've previously worked with SQL Server tables containing over 250 million rows and we didn't think about performance over design and we never had any issues with the speed of  inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have three tables with identical primary keys.  Assuming you make these a clustered index on the tables, then access between the tables will be quite fast.

You should set up your relationships so they make sense.  From the naming scheme, I would guess that `DepositAccountStatus` is related to `DepositAccount`.  Hence, I would put the foreign key relationship to that table.

This is not a performance issue.  This is simply modeling the data correctly.

Another question is why the status table has the same primary key as `DepositAccount`.  Why not just put the status directly in that table?

Comment: You hit the exact point boss. Using different `DEPOSITACCOUNTSTATUS` table is indeed a bad design.